# Consider the limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{y^4}{x^2+y^4}.$ Where did I mistake?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Determine whether the limit $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\quad \frac{y^4}{x^2+y^4}.$$

If $(x,y)$ approaches $(0,0)$ satisfying $x=y^2$, then $\frac{y^4}{x^2+y^4}=\frac{1}{2}\to \frac{1}{2}$, whilst if $(x,y)$ approaches $(0,0)$ satisfying $x=0$, then $\frac{y^4}{x^2+y^4}=1\to 1$. Thus the limit doesn't exist.

However, if I consider the polar coodinates, then $$\frac{y^4}{x^2+y^4}=\frac{r^4\sin^4 t}{r^2\cos^2 t+r^4\sin^4 t}
=\frac{r^2\sin^4 t}{\cos^2 t+r^2\sin^4 t}
\to 0$$ as $r\to 0.$ Thus the limit is $0$ ?

There should be a mistake somewhere but I cannot find. Where did I mistake ?

Comment: For $\cos t =0$ before limit process You have constant fraction with value $1$ and it's limit is not zero.

Comment: @zkutch That's more of an answer than a comment.

Comment: If you consider $t$ as fixed in your last limit, then you miss some ways of approaching $(0,0)$. As said in the previous comments, taking $\cos(t)=0$ gives the paths with $x=0$, but you can also take $t$ such that $\cos^2(t)=r^2\sin^4(t)$ to get the paths with $x=y^2$, and so on.

Comment: I got it. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: It is more convenient to use a modification of the polar coordinates, namely $x=r\cos t$ and $y^2=r\sin t,$ $0\le t\le \pi.$  The expression takes the form  $\sin^2t$, so the limit does not exist when $r\to 0^+$ (which is equivalent to $(x,y)\to (0,0)$ ).